# opening a python file in cmd ,an Electron error

Tags: python, electron

**I want to open a python file in cmd but after writing the directory,file is opened in vs code a I will get this in cmd:**

[main 2020-08-14T06:28:09.084Z] update#setState idle
(node:1892) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:1892) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[8368:5624:0814/105809.770:ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(469)] failed to stat report
(node:1892) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:1892) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:12172) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:12172) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[main 2020-08-14T06:28:39.095Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2020-08-14T06:28:39.802Z] update#setState idle

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Having puzzled over this for a while when I hit it this morning, I think there are two things going on:

1. If you start VSCode from the command line, it issues some warnings about Electron deprecations.
2. If you intend to run `python my_file.py` but instead run `my_file.py`, a possible outcome is that VSCode is configured (has configured itself?) to open the file.

In my case the reason for the missing `python` in the command was a CMake line `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} build_helper_script.py` where PYTHON_EXECUTABLE hadn't been set, but presumably there are various routes to this mystifying warning. JS errors are quite unexpected when compiling C++...

Answer (score 0):

Share some code from the file - looks like there is something with the js code in it.
Other thing - some of the errors are just a warning for deprecating modules.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for solve this problem you should  in Git command line before name of file write python